# How can i use a variable in the when consition in the case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a `sql-script` which readout data sets that are wrong.
a data set is, for example, wrong when the `@differenz` is bigger than 0(that means the end is bevor the begin)

so I ask in the case statement if the `differenz` is bigger than zero to put a one if it is correct or a zero when not but I can't call the @differenz variable I got this error
Must declare the scalar variable `"@differenz"`.

How can I call this variable

```
USE [ws_Benjamin]
GO

/****** Object:  View [fu].[FUanalyse]    Script Date: 30.09.2019 13:43:25 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO




DECLARE @differenz bigint
DECLARE @fidFirst bigint
DECLARE @beginFirst bigint
DECLARE @endFirst bigint
DECLARE @fidSecond bigint
DECLARE @beginSecond bigint
DECLARE @endSecond bigint

DECLARE @first as TABLE
(
    fidFirst bigint,
    beginFirst bigint,  
    endFirst bigint
)

DECLARE @second as TABLE
(
    fidSecond bigint,
    beginSecond bigint,  
    endSecond bigint
)
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT fid, DATUMZEITBEGIN, DATUMZEITEND FROM fu.FUrearranged 
    order by fid

OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @fidFirst, @beginFirst,@endFirst

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @fidSecond, @beginSecond, @endSecond
        if (@endFirst-@beginSecond)>0
            begin

                set @differenz = (@endFirst-@beginSecond)
                --print 'there it is'
            end
        else
            begin
                set @differenz = -100
            end     
END

CLOSE myCursor -- must to close
DEALLOCATE myCursor -- must to deallocate

go
ALTER VIEW [fu].[FUanalyse]
as
--with fus(personFID ,anzahlFU) as ( select fu.FUrearranged.fid, ranked from fu.FUrearranged)

select id, fid, dbfid, ranked, typ, datum, F1,F2,F3,G1,G2,G3,datumzeitbegin,datumzeitend,

case
when substring(typ, 4, 8) = 'ärztlich' and austritt between convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(datumzeitbegin,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '),121) and 
                                                                                                  convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(datumzeitend,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '),121) and 
                                                                                                  eintritt < convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(datumzeitbegin,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '),121) then '1'
/*when substring(typ, 4, 8) = 'ärztlich' and eintritt > convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(datumzeitbegin,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '),121) and
                                                                                 austritt < convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(datumzeitend,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '),121) then 'Ungültig (Aufenthalt kürzer als FU)'
when datumzeitend is null then 'Ungültig (Enddatum nicht vorhanden)'*/
else '0'
end as FUlaufend,
case
when substring(typ, 4, 8) = 'ärztlich' and eintritt > convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(datumzeitbegin,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '),121) and
                                                                                 austritt < convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(datumzeitend,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '),121) then '1'
else '0'
end as FUzuKurz,
case
when G1 = 0 and G2 = 0 and G3 = 0 then '1'
else '0'
end as G_Ungültig,
case  
when F1 = 0 and F2 = 0 and F3 = 0 then '1'
else '0'
end as F_Ungültig,
case
when DATUMZEITEND = null then '1'
else '0'
end as FUkeinEnddatum,
case
when @differenz > 0 then '1'
else '0'
end as F_Überscheindung

from fu.FUrearranged
GO
```

Comment: `CASE` **expression**. `Case` statements don't exist in T-SQL.

Comment: What is the actual goal you have here? The fact that you are using a `CURSOR` infers a design flaw or that you haven't considered a set-based approach (which will be (significantly) faster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by your GO statements, they represent a new query batch, so variables don't carry over after a GO. However you are altering a view, which is required by SQL to be the first statement of a Batch, so removing the GOs won't work in your case.

What I would suggest doing is something like this

```
create view test as select 1 a

select * from test

declare @a int = 2;
declare @sql_statement nvarchar(250) ='alter view test as select '+CAST(@a as nvarchar)+' as a';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_statement;
```

You can build your Alter view statment like a string and then execute it with the stored procedure "sp_executesql", this way you don't need a GO to execute the Alter View.

---

Edit: Be extremely careful with what you drop onto sp_executesql, it's really easy to cause SQL Injection if you use it carelessly.

Comment: It's not `sp_executesql` that is open to injection, it's concatenating strings and no sanitising the values that is the injection problem. something like `EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT 1 AS One;';` can never suffer injection. The key way to ensure that when using dynamic SQL is to quote your objects, and parametrise values wherever possible.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, that's why i said to be careful about what you drop onto sp_executesql. In this case I meant to clarify so that people don't go around using it carelessly, for the actual use case of OP there's no need to parametrize as it's only using an int, the rest of the query is hardcoded.